# Tamil Font in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, fonts, tamil

I searched a lot but could find a good tamil font file to use in my android app. I think from Android 4.0 tamil font is automatically supported. But I need to port my application to BlackBerry PlayBook as well. So i am forced to use Android 2.3.3 which does not have native support for tamil fonts. I tried many fonts - TSCII, Unicode. So far, the best I Used is Microsoft's latha.ttf but the letters are so much scrambled. Does anyone know a good font that works in Android 2.3.3?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow, as it's 100% a matter of personal opinion and whatever app you're making. Personally, I'd use Roboto. (You can download this from FontSquirrel or DAFont for free.)

Comment: Why does porting to Blackberry imply that you must use 2.3?

Comment: @Simon The BlackBerry packager (for converting Android apps) only takes apps that run on 2.3.3, I believe.

Comment: Simon, at present blackberry has android runtime support only for 2.3.3. Not any later versions.

Comment: Eric, It's not a personal opinion. I am not asking which tamil font looks good. I am asking which files works good. I hope you understand the difference.

Comment: I use TSCII and it works fine. what problem are you facing with TSCII?

Comment: @Selva, I tried many TSCII fonts. Either I see just boxes or scrambled letters (e.g. In "கோ", "க" comes at front.) Can you point me any free TSCII font file to use? Which one you using in your application?

Comment: @ Eric, Simon C.A. McCann, Graham Smith, EdChum: I dont understand how possibly this question will solicit debate or argument. Btw, "Tamil" is a language and not type of font. I need to support tamil language letters on my application and I am not able to show the characters properly. So I am seeking help from other developers who using tamil fonts in their application. Is that wrong?

Comment: Check this out. This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267292/tamil-font-in-android/15496145#15496145

Comment: @Mayu, Already, I got help from you on another thread and released my enThirukkural App. Thank you so much for digging up this :)

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu awesome bro :)

Comment: @Mayu, I am using Bamini font within a webview. Using a <B> tag does not work to show some part of the text in bold. Can you please tell how to achieve this?

Comment: thats weired. if `<b></b>` doesn't work why not try `<strong></strong>` and see.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan Neither of them works.So, I increased the font size by 2 where bold is used. And the solution seems ok. Now my problem is, I am not able to show Kannada text on ICS. Have you worked on Kannada font before? I think some encoding similar to your bamini will do the trick. Please let me know your suggestion.

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu Other than Tamil I didn't do for any other encoding. But you can check a non unicode kannada font and same converting feature I suppose.